# How to keep login screen from going blank with minimal RHEL install?

Tags: terminal, rhel, startup, display

I am running Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.4.  I have done a minimal install so that I don't have X11, xorg, xset or anything x related installed.  I am trying to keep the monitor from going blank.  When I log in I can run the following command which does the trick:

```
setterm -blank 0 -powerdown 0 -powersave off
```

However, when I put that in a script to run at boot time (I call the script from rc.local for now) it doesn't work.  I am trying to keep the screen on even before a login.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least the first two parts are realised by sending an escape sequence to the console handler, as can be demonstrated like this:

```
$ setterm -blank 0 -powerdown 0 | od -c
0000000 033   [   9   ;   0   ] 033   [   1   4   ;   0   ]
0000015
```

The easiest way of doing this automatically is to add this output to the file `/etc/issue` which is sent to the screen before the `login:` prompt:

```
# setterm -blank 0 -powerdown 0 >> /etc/issue
```

Now the escape sequence is always sent to the screen.

Comment: Is there a more elegant way to do this? For example putting a script into rcX.d?

Comment: Sure, trivial if you have the info already given. Put "TERM=linux setterm -blank -powerdown 0 > /dev/console" into the script of your choice. I just wonder if having to execute a script and a binary every boot is more elegant than having /etc/issue be a couple of bytes longer.

Comment: Can /etc/issue can change with an upgrade of the OS? I've been researching this for 2 days and I'm surprised why isn't there an init.d service for managing the screen saver. Could save a couple of MWhs if turned on by default on all linux systems worldwide..